# How to add an identifier that uniquely identifies a subset of columns in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table as follows:

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
| a    |    i | x    |
| b    |    j | y    |
| a    |    i | z    |
+------+------+------+
```

What is the best way to add a column that uniquely identifies Col 1 and Col 2 only? The output table should look like:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | a    |    i | x    |
|  2 | b    |    j | y    |
|  1 | a    |    i | z    |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Why isn't it 2,1,2?

Comment: It can be @Strawberry

Comment: OK, so how do we choose?

Comment: It could be either, it could be random numbers as long as they uniquely identify Col1 and Col2. Like a primary key for only Col1 and Col2.

Comment: That's a shame, because that potentially makes the problem even harder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `dense_rank()` for this:

```
select dense_rank() over(order by col1, col2) id, t.*
from mytable t
```

Comment: I'm not running MySQL 8.0 unfortunately, so that function doesn't exist